# Java - Where should I initialise variables for memory efficiency?

Tags: java, performance, variables, memory

Is it okay for memory to initialise a variable inside a method that will be called rather frequently?
Basically, is this example method:

```
int amount;
private boolean method() {
    amount = Random.nextInt(0, 100);
    return amount == 50;
}
```

More/less/the same in terms of memory efficiency to this method:

```
private boolean method() {
    int amount = Random.nextInt(0, 100);
    return amount == 50;
}
```

And yeah, I know these aren't the best examples, and that there is some redundancy to them. Sorry about that.

Anyway, thanks in advance.

Comment: Second one seems better , provided you don't need to have `amount` as instance variable or class variable !

Comment: Local variables are always pushed onto the stack, while instance variables live on the heap.

Comment: It's almost always best to declare variables to have the narrowest scope possible, both for efficiency and to reduce programming errors.  (Narrowly-scoped variables are less likely to be accidentally misused, and they're more likely to be thread safe.)  But if you're concerned about efficiency, your algorithm and the _types_ of variables you use are more likely to have an effect.  For example, you can eliminate the temporary variable in your method altogether and let the compiler optimize the storage.

Comment: In Java local variables are almost always more efficient to access.  In the above example `amount` (if local) would probably just stay in a register and never even be written to storage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference in efficiency, if any, is highly likely to be completely irrelevant. If `amount` does not need to be visible outside the method, prefer the second version as it does not have unnecessary side effects and is thread-safe.

To expand on the last point, if multiple threads were to call `method()` on the same object, the first version is open to a race condition.

Answer (score 4):

From *Effective Java (2nd Edition)*:

Never sacrifice sound architectual principles (such as **information hiding**) for **performance**.

> **Item 55: Optimize judiciously**
>
> > - Don't sacrifice sound architectural principles for performance. Strive to write good programs rather than fast ones.
> > - Good programs embody the principle of information hiding: where possible, they localize design decisions within individual modules, so individual decisions can be changed without affecting the remainder of the system.

and:

> **Item 45: Minimize the scope of local variabless**
>
> > By minimizing the scope of local variables, you increase the readability and maintainability of your code and reduce the likelihood of error.
> >
> > Older programming languages, such as C, mandated that local variables must be declared at the head of a block, and some programmers continue to do this out of habit. It’s a habit worth breaking. As a gentle reminder, Java lets you declare variables anywhere a statement is legal.
> >
> > - The most powerful technique for minimizing the scope of a local variable to declare it is first used.
> > - Nearly every local variable declaration should contain an initialier.

So the best approach seems to be the second one.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't really be worried about memory efficiency as much as I would be worried about errors due to **concurrent access**.

```
    return amount == 50;
```

When this class is used across multiple instances, an instance variable's `amount` can vary. Without proper memory barriers this would lead to erroneous results. The int falls out of scope when the method completes, if it is a local variable.

Speaking of which, why is a variable needed here anyway ? Will this not do ?

```
return Random.nextInt(0, 100) == 50;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And yeah, I acknowledged the redundancy; I simply couldn't think of a better example.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is better if you do not need to use it in other methods; the performance is not a concern since the variable inside a method allocated on the stack, which is extremely fast.

However in your particular case this approach would be better, and a good IDE would suggest it:

```
private boolean method() {    
    return Random.nextInt(0, 100) == 50;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And yeah, I noted that they weren't the best possible examples, mainly due to the `amount` variable being redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are internal to methods. It is better to keep each variable's scope as small as possible. But if more than one method needs to access a variable, then define an instance or class variable.