# Initialization in declaration

Tags: java

In Java, is the below code a good practice or bad also suggest a memory-efficient way

```
int num1 = (int) Math.random(),
    num2 = (int) Math.random(),
    sum  = (num1 + num2);
 
System.out.print("sum is " + sum);
```

I want to know the efficient and most appropriate convention.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - Where should I initialise variables for memory efficiency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131221/java-where-should-i-initialise-variables-for-memory-efficiency)

Comment: There isn’t any efficiency difference. It’s recommended to declare only one variable in each declaration, so terminate each line with semicolon (`;`) and start each new line with `int`.

Comment: As an aside using `Math.random()` for random integers is not my preferred way, and both of your numbers will be 0 always. Since Java 17 use the [`java.util.random`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/package-summary.html) package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is perfectly fine to do so in Java. Regarding the performance and memory consumption, your approach will make no  difference compared to a line-by-line declaration of your variables like so:

```
int num1 = (int) Math.random();
int num2 = (int) Math.random();
int sum  = (num1 + num2);
```

The default Java compiler will transform your variable declarations into optimized machine code, so the two different approaches usually result in the same bytecode being executed by the Java Virtual Machine on the end device.

I tested the output of the standard compiler that comes with [OpenJDK17](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk/17/). 
 I created two test files named `TestFileSL.java` (single-line variable declaration) and `TestFileML.java` (multi-line variable declaration) and then compiled them to .class files using the `javac` command. Then I printed the content of the class files using the `javap -c` command. The output of the two files is provided below. As you can see, they are absolutely identical aside from the class name:

---

```
public class TestFileSL {
  public TestFileSL();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #7                  // Method java/lang/Math.random:()D
       3: d2i
       4: istore_1
       5: invokestatic  #7                  // Method java/lang/Math.random:()D
       8: d2i
       9: istore_2
      10: iload_1
      11: iload_2
      12: iadd
      13: istore_3
      14: getstatic     #13                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      17: iload_3
      18: invokedynamic #19,  0             // InvokeDynamic #0:makeConcatWithConstants:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
      23: invokevirtual #23                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.print:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      26: return
}
```

---

```
public class TestFileML {
  public TestFileML();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #7                  // Method java/lang/Math.random:()D
       3: d2i
       4: istore_1
       5: invokestatic  #7                  // Method java/lang/Math.random:()D
       8: d2i
       9: istore_2
      10: iload_1
      11: iload_2
      12: iadd
      13: istore_3
      14: getstatic     #13                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      17: iload_3
      18: invokedynamic #19,  0             // InvokeDynamic #0:makeConcatWithConstants:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
      23: invokevirtual #23                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.print:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      26: return
}
```

---

As a side note, if you code is using the static method [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) of the `java.lang.Math` package, this method returns a random `double` between 0 and 1. So when casting this to an `int`, the variables and the sum will always be 0. To access a static method of a class, you write the class name, so in your case it should be `Math.random()` instead of `math.random()`.

Comment: Noted........thanks for the answer.